# Unable to shut down

Tags: 10.10, shutdown

After installing a wireless keyboard and mouse I cannot shutdown my pc.

I have tried to shut down from the console as well, but the result doesn't change. 
How  can resolve my problem?
thanks in advance

ciao
h.

Comment: More information please, especially what is happening if you try to shut down the PC.

Comment: Did you get any error during shutdown?

Comment: Thanks for answering Bobby, the computer blocks to the last screen all black with only ubuntu written and completing dot under and nothing happen waiting hours..

Comment: @ karthick87: No, I do not get error

Comment: The receiver signal it's USB maybe some problem due to this?

Comment: What is the output, if any, of the `sudo shutdown -P now` command?

Comment: I do not get output automatically arrives splash screen with written ubuntu and computer stop there..

Comment: What do you get when running "sudo shutdown -h now" in a terminal ?

Comment: Hi Pascal thanks for answering! All my problem was due to a problem with my bios upgradeing it I resolved thanks ciao h.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, but just to answer the shut-down part: press the power button on the computer. Sixty seconds later, it will start a shutdown.

Comment: Yes I do but how to stop this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same as Christopher said, you can get that Window, By pressing Cntrl + Alt + Delete button also.

Comment: There is a way to understand what is the process that goes in error?

Comment: Yeah, Try shutdown from the proposed way, see if that works or not. If your system does not shutdown, then Open the Log File Viewer and see the logs. May be that will give you more information to get the correct answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for hints I'll check the logs and post results. thanks again! ciao h.

Comment: what log i have to check to see problem during shutdown? thanks in advance ciao h.